# How to overwrite a text file in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, io, overwrite

I am reading a text file called charList.txt to my GUI and then I made some changes through the GUI. I am hoping to save all the changes to the same text file but I don't know how. So I created a new text file called new.text and I rename it to overwrite my charList.text. But it failed. Can someone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

```
      try {
                FileWriter edit = new FileWriter("new.txt");
                PrintWriter pedit = new PrintWriter(edit);
                FileReader fr = null;
                  String line = "null";
                    try{
                        fr = new FileReader("charList.txt");
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    while(line != null){
                        try{
                            line = bf.readLine();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e1){
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (line != null){
                            fields = line.split("\t");
                            if (Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()) != Integer.parseInt(fields[0])){
                                pedit.println(line);
                            }
                            else{
                                pedit.println(Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()) + "\t" + moneyBefore + "\t" + userName + "\t" + fields[3] + "\t" + fields[4] + "\t"
                                        + fields[5] + "\t" + moneyAfter);
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                    pedit.close();
                    bf.close();
                    File old = new File("charList.txt");
                    old.delete();
                    File oldfile =new File("new.txt");
                    File newfile =new File("charList.txt");

                    if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile)){
                        System.out.println("Rename succesful");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Rename failed");
                    }

            }
              catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
              }

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Close both streams.  Delete oldFile before rename.

Comment: Please close the streams inside `finally` blocks, too.  FindBugs might help teach some of the basics of closing resources appropriately here.

Comment: how do I delete the old file? and by streams you mean `br` and `pedit` right?

Comment: 1) File.delete().  2) Yes ... that's what he means.

Comment: I made changes but still failed. I've updated my code and could you take another look at it?

Comment: Did the old.delete() succeed?  Check the return code to see if it is false.  Is this on Windows?